# Partially transpose a dataframe in R

Tags: r, reshape

Given the following set of data:

```
 transect <- c("B","N","C","D","H","J","E","L","I","I")
 sampler <- c(rep("J",5),rep("W",5))
 species <- c("ROB","HAW","HAW","ROB","PIG","HAW","PIG","PIG","HAW","HAW")
 weight <- c(2.80,52.00,56.00,2.80,16.00,55.00,16.20,18.30,52.50,57.00)
 wingspan <- c(13.9, 52.0, 57.0, 13.7, 11.0,52.5, 10.7, 11.1, 52.3, 55.1)
 week <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9)
 # Warning to R newbs: Really bad idea to use this code
 ex <- as.data.frame(cbind(transect,sampler,species,weight,wingspan,week))
```

What I’m trying to achieve is to transpose the species and its associated information on weight and wingspan. For a better idea of the expected result please see below. My data set is about half a million lines long with approximately 200 different species so it will be a very large dataframe.

```
      transect sampler week ROBweight HAWweight PIGweight ROBwingspan HAWwingspan PIGwingspan
1         B       J    1       2.8       0.0       0.0        13.9         0.0         0.0
2         N       J    2       0.0      52.0       0.0         0.0        52.0         0.0
3         C       J    3       0.0      56.0       0.0         0.0        57.0         0.0
4         D       J    4       2.8       0.0       0.0        13.7         0.0         0.0
5         H       J    5       0.0       0.0      16.0         0.0         0.0        11.0
6         J       W    6       0.0      55.0       0.0         0.0        52.5         0.0
7         E       W    7       0.0       0.0      16.2         0.0         0.0        10.7
8         L       W    8       0.0       0.0      18.3         0.0         0.0        11.1
9         I       W    9       0.0      52.5       0.0         0.0        52.3         0.0
10        I       W    9       0.0      57.0       0.0         0.0        55.1         0.0
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried. [Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Thanks.

Comment: Maybe start with `??transpose`, and see where that leads you.

Comment: By the way, this is a terrible way to construct your sample data, unless you really want numeric values as factors. In the future, skip the `as.data.frame(cbind(...` part and just use `data.frame(...`.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine that this irregular dataset can be reformed to make sense in a wide format. I think the reasons for this effort should be laid out and carefully examined.

Comment: Dwin – I agree it is a funny format and you are only seeing part of it!! However, in the past couple of years a lot of effort was put into developing functions (not by me) which use this format. So, analysing it is quite strait forward getting it in the right format can be a pain.

Comment: Henrick- I apologise for not adding what I have done so far. I will add it for sure in future posts as I can see it usefulness. Just for the record the path I was taking was nested FOR loops and I don’t think I was going anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't currently have unique "id" variables, which will create problems for the usual suspects of `reshape` and `dcast`.

Here's a solution. I've used `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package, but it's pretty easy to create your own unique ID variable using many different methods.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(reshape2)
idvars <- c("transect", "sampler", "week")
ex <- getanID(ex, id.vars=idvars)
```

From here, you have two options:

#### `reshape` from base R:

```
reshape(ex, direction = "wide", 
        idvar=c("transect", "sampler", "week", ".id"), 
        timevar="species")
```

#### `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2"

First, `melt` your data into a "long" form.

```
exL <- melt(ex, id.vars=c(idvars, ".id", "species"))
```

Then, `cast` your data into a wide form.

```
dcast(exL, transect + sampler + week + .id ~ species + variable)
#    transect sampler week .id HAW_weight HAW_wingspan PIG_weight PIG_wingspan ROB_weight ROB_wingspan
# 1         B       J    1   1         NA           NA         NA           NA        2.8         13.9
# 2         C       J    3   1       56.0         57.0         NA           NA         NA           NA
# 3         D       J    4   1         NA           NA         NA           NA        2.8         13.7
# 4         E       W    7   1         NA           NA       16.2         10.7         NA           NA
# 5         H       J    5   1         NA           NA       16.0         11.0         NA           NA
# 6         I       W    9   1       52.5         52.3         NA           NA         NA           NA
# 7         I       W    9   2       57.0         55.1         NA           NA         NA           NA
# 8         J       W    6   1       55.0         52.5         NA           NA         NA           NA
# 9         L       W    8   1         NA           NA       18.3         11.1         NA           NA
# 10        N       J    2   1       52.0         52.0         NA           NA         NA           NA
```

---

#### A better option: "data.table"

Alternatively (and perhaps preferably), you can use the "data.table" package (at least version 1.8.11) as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2) ## Also required here
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’
DT <- data.table(ex)
DT[, .id := sequence(.N), by = c("transect", "sampler", "week")]
DTL <- melt(DT, measure.vars=c("weight", "wingspan"))
dcast.data.table(DTL, transect + sampler + week + .id ~ species + variable)
#     transect sampler week .id HAW_weight HAW_wingspan PIG_weight PIG_wingspan ROB_weight ROB_wingspan
#  1:        B       J    1   1         NA           NA         NA           NA        2.8         13.9
#  2:        C       J    3   1       56.0         57.0         NA           NA         NA           NA
#  3:        D       J    4   1         NA           NA         NA           NA        2.8         13.7
#  4:        E       W    7   1         NA           NA       16.2         10.7         NA           NA
#  5:        H       J    5   1         NA           NA       16.0         11.0         NA           NA
#  6:        I       W    9   1       52.5         52.3         NA           NA         NA           NA
#  7:        I       W    9   2       57.0         55.1         NA           NA         NA           NA
#  8:        J       W    6   1       55.0         52.5         NA           NA         NA           NA
#  9:        L       W    8   1         NA           NA       18.3         11.1         NA           NA
# 10:        N       J    2   1       52.0         52.0         NA           NA         NA           NA
```

---

Add `fill = 0` to either of the `dcast` versions to replace `NA` values with 0.

Comment: Ananda- I do agree with you it is a bad construct of the example dataset. It won’t matter in this case as the functions I’m going to use do check what type of class it is and change it if necessary. However, you made a good point which I’ll take on board. As for your solutions the first one worked as a charm on the example. I’m going to apply it to the entire dataset now and hope for the best.

Comment: Your second solution the data.table one throws me an error on the first line of code:
 “Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , `:=`(.id, sequence(.N)), by = c("transect",  :   unused argument(s) (by = c("transect", "sampler", "week"))”. 
I could only load the package 1.8.10 for some funny reason the 1.8.11 wasn’t available so that might be it.

Comment: @PatraoPedro, not *might* but *will*. See the R-Forge `data.table` page to update to the most recent version available: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240

Comment: I've just installed the new version of R 3.0.2 and installed data.table version 1.8.11 but still no joy trying replicate your code. Many thanks

Comment: @PatraoPedro, Perhaps you were missing one line that I forgot to include in my answer when copying and pasting: `DT <- data.table(ex)`. In other words, convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table` first.